# Everything is breaking in Android Studio 0.8.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio from 0.6.1 to 0.8.1

None of my code changed, but the new update breaks everything. It seems like the entire Android SDK is not loading properly. A given class ends up looking like this:

[image]

The project is question still uses the old ANT compilation system, but I have another project using Gradle and the same problem is happening. When I go back to my old install of 0.6.1 it works fine.

I checked the Project Structure to make sure the Project SDK was pointing to the right place and it is.

The gradle console returns no errors when syncing the project with gradle:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :wearable:generateDebugSources, :facebook:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:facebook:compileLint
:facebook:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preBuild
:facebook:preReleaseBuild
:facebook:checkReleaseManifest
:facebook:preDebugBuild
:facebook:preDebugTestBuild
:facebook:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:prepareReleaseDependencies
:facebook:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareBandsintownGimportFacebookUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices5077Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComViewpagerindicatorLibrary241Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:preBuild
:wearable:preDebugBuild
:wearable:checkDebugManifest
:wearable:preReleaseBuild
:wearable:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices5077Library UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:prepareDebugDependencies
:wearable:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:wearable:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:checkDebugManifest
:facebook:prepareDebugDependencies
:facebook:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.053 secs
```

The Gradle classpath is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+`

The build.gradle file from the project's app folder by request:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.bandsintown'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 113
        versionName '4.6.5'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

Actually, I noticed that the first line of this was wrong when copying this. It used to be `apply plugin: 'android'` but that has been changed for this new version of Gradle to instead be what you see there with `com.android.application`. However, changing this line still gives me the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Error messages? Does it build and run?

Comment: Attempting to run the project results in errors which say "package android.view/widget/etc does not exist"

For some reason it is just not recognizing Android despite it all being configured correctly, at least in previous Android Studio versions.

Comment: I don't know anything about Ant-based projects, but for Gradle-based projects, any errors you get when syncing the project to Gradle files would be informative.

Comment: I'll switch to the gradle project and see what it comes up with, give me a moment. Thanks

Comment: I added the Gradle console output to the original question body. Syncing with Gradle gives no errors, yet any class provided by the Android SDK cannot be found.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle inside the app folder

Comment: @HiemanshuSharma the build.gradle file from the app folder is included in the original question body. Thanks

Comment: I know that last week when I was trying to work with my android projects in Eclipse, it wouldn't find the path to the adk until I uninstalled the Eclipse plug-in and re-installed it. I've never used Android Studio before, but maybe doing something like that would help?

Comment: Still not working on 0.8.4

Comment: Are you using the SDK that is now packaged with AS or are you using your old, previously-installed SDK? I suggest that you double-check that AS is configured to point to the one that you are using.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice In both my working version (0.6.1) and non-working version (0.8.+) I am pointing to the same SDK

Comment: Just tried creating a new brand new project through the creation wizard in 0.8.4, it has all the same android errors as well. Anything in the main com.android package is not working, but other libraries and modules are. I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when upgrading from 0.6.1 to 0.8.0
Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure how I solved it, but I think following saved me:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ibma.ibmaapp"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
...
</manifest>
```

1. add the sdkVersion in the AndroidManifest.xml (see above)
2. click Menu "File" > "Invalidated Caches / Restart..."
3. if not fixed yet open the SDK Manager and uninstalled the "Android L" and "Android W4.4" package (if installed)

check again, maybe repeat step 2

Comment: My goal is to compile on 4.4W so omitting it isn't an option. Tried your other suggestions though, and unfortunately none worked.

Comment: How does ur sdk manager look like (regarding installed packages)        U downloaded android studio + sdk right? Did you replace ur old sdk with the new one, or which one are u using?

Comment: I'm using the SDK found inside the Android Studio.app/sdk directory. I point to the same one on my older Android Studio install and it works fine. Obviously the older version is a different .app directory, but I still point to the newer directory for the sdk folder so it should be the same.

Comment: On the older Android Studio Install you also compiled with 4.4W, right?
But actually I don't know any further steps, sry...